# React Component changing props on internal event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react component where I need to show hide a dom element depending on a props. Below you will find a basic idea of the problem. The code is simplified off course.

```
<UploadManager
    show={show}
>
{content}
</UploadManager>
```

### The Component

```
export default class UploadManager extends React.Component{

    openDrawer(){
        // change props.open ???
    }

    render(){
        <Drawer
          visible={this.props.show}
        >
         <p>Content</p>
        </Drawer>
        <Button onClick={this.openDrawer} />
    }
}
```

### Explanation

1. `show` props of the component `UploadManager` open/close a [Drawer component](https://ant.design/components/drawer/)
2. The parent component can pass the `show` props and show/hide the Drawer. I got this part working correctly.
3. **Need help with**: The component have a floating button. When Clicked it should open (show) the Drawer. Meaning it should set `this.props.show` to `true`.

I tried to maintain a internal state of the component which manages the show/hide property of the drawer but it becomes too buggy because of the props + state involvement.

Comment: where do you use the `show` property to show/hide the `Drawer` ? Moreover manage the `open` variable in the state not in the props https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo on the code. Fixed it now.

Comment: ok your solution is ok. Is `show` part of the state of the parent component ? Can you show use the code of `onClickShowButton` in your answer ?

Comment: Just updated it. This method is working for me now. With any side effect. I tried to manage a internal state. It quickly become mess because parent passes the props downstream also the button changes the internal state. Had to work with `componentDidUpdate` comparing prevState and prevProps. Too much room for bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to pass callback from the parent to change the prop. Below is the solution to this problem.

`this.onClickShowButton()` is a method of the parent.

### Parent Component

```
onClickShowButton = () => {
    this.setState({show: true});
}

render(){
    return <UploadManager
        show={this.state.show}
        onClickShowButton={this.onClickShowButton}
    >
    {content}
    </UploadManager>
}
```

### On the component

Checks if the callback is a function, then executes it. Does the job perfectly!

```
export default class UploadManager extends React.Component{

    openDrawer = () => {
        if (typeof(this.props.onClickShowButton) === 'function') {
            this.props['onClickShowButton']();
        }
    }

    render(){
        <Drawer
          visible={this.props.show}
        >
         <p>Content</p>
        </Drawer>
        <Button onClick={this.openDrawer} />
    }
}
```

If so it executes it. I don't know how correct this method is. If anyone have a better answer, I am open to it.

Comment: better use defaultProps instead of checking type

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is fine except you don't need the `openDrawer` in the `UploadManager` component, actually it could be a dummy functional component, here is a possible solution :

```
const UploadManager = ({show, onClick}) => (
   <Drawer visible={show}>
     <p>Content</p>
   </Drawer>
   <Button onClick={onClick} />
);
```

Then the **parent** component would be

```
onClickShowButton = () => {
   this.setState({show: true});
}

render(){
   return (
     <UploadManager 
          show={this.state.show} 
          onClick={this.onClickShowButton}
     >
       {content}
     </UploadManager>
   );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code example I gave is simplified though :) I appreciate your input. I think i am on the right track. I often end up posting solution on my own Q as my brain triggers after I post a problem :D

Comment: you are one the right way, don"t create another state in child component if the parent already have one, it will be a mess and really hard to maintain

Comment: Yes, agreed! Stateless component is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

The Component:

```
export default class UploadManager extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            openDrawer : props.show
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.setState({
            openDrawer: this.props.show
        })
    }
    openDrawer = () =>{
        this.setState({
            openDrawer : !this.state.openDrawer
        })
    }
    render() {
        <div>
            <Drawer
                visible={this.state.openDrawer}
            >
                <p>Content</p>
            </Drawer>
            <Button onClick={this.openDrawer} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` is deprecated now.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé the componentdidupdate and componentwillreceiveprops are different if you know.

Comment: I don't think they work in a similar way. We can't change the name of componentWillReceiveProps to componentDidUpdate for the same functioning.

Comment: In componentWillReceiveProps setState() will not result in an infinite loop but in componentDidUpdate() it will be as it is not controlled with some condition.

Answer (score 0):

if the parent component just sets the initial state of your upload manager to shows or hides the drawer when it first renders then you can do this:

```
    <UploadManager
        show={show}
    >
    {content}
    </UploadManager>

    export default class UploadManager extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {
              open: props.show
           }
        }
        openDrawer(){
            this.setState({open: true});
        }

        render(){
            <Drawer
              visible={this.state.open}
            >
             <p>Content</p>
            </Drawer>
            <Button onClick={this.openDrawer} />
        }
    }
```

in this way the initial state of your component would be the show property that its parent passes and then when the button gets clicked, this state gets updated and the drawer is being shown based on the component state. But if you want to control the show property that the parent is passing and you want to control your drawer with that, you should do this:

```
    <UploadManager
        show={show}
        onUpdateShowState={()=>{this.setState({show: true})}}
    >
    {content}
    </UploadManager>

    export default class UploadManager extends React.Component{

        openDrawer(){
            this.props.onUpdateShowState()
        }

        render(){
            <Drawer
              visible={this.props.show}
            >
             <p>Content</p>
            </Drawer>
            <Button onClick={this.openDrawer} />
        }
    }
```

in the above code you are controling your drawer with the show property that gets passed to your component and you are updating it by calling another property that updates the parent state with this: this.setState({show: true}) -> so here this referes to your parent component where show has been defined and should be written inside the parent component of the uploadManager

Comment: Thanks, My solution is similar. I think this is the right way of doing it.